# Getting Noise and echo in Quickblox audio/video chat Sample

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat

I have referred [this example](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android) to implement audio/video chat functionality in my app, but I'm getting a lot of noise and echo during audio/video call. So can anybody please tell me how can I improve the voice quality, (I mean is there any setting I need to do in my code or in my device..?) Thank you..!